# Existe alguma maneira de enviar imagem por JSON para uma api?

Tags: json, api, file-upload

Quero enviar uma imagem (vou salvá-la em banco mesmo), porém não sei como faço para enviá-la junto no `POST`.

Estou usando `AngularJs`:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="user.imageProfile">
```

---

```
$scope.register = function (user) {

    if (user.password != user.passwordConfirm) {
        $rootScope.showToast("Confirmação de senha inválida!");
        return null;
    }

    $http.post($rootScope.serviceBase + "users", user).then(function () {
        $rootScope.showToast("Cadastrado com sucesso");
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    });
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6150289/4190610

Comment: Me diz uma coisa, no momento que o usuário escolhe uma imagem, **`user.imageProfile`** tem qual valor?

Comment: @jbueno ele nem mostra o atributo no objeto user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi convertendo a imagem para `Base64`, utilizei [angular-base64-upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload), ficou assim:

*Input:*

```
<input type="file" ng-model="image" base-sixty-four-input>
```

*Controller:*

```
$scope.register = function (user) {
    if (user.password != user.passwordConfirm) {
        $rootScope.showToast("Confirmação de senha inválida!");
        return null;
    }

    $scope.user.imageProfile = $scope.image.base64;

    $http.post($rootScope.serviceBase + "users", user).then(function () {
        $rootScope.showToast("Cadastrado com sucesso");
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    });
};
```

*Exibição:*

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{ userAuthenticated.imageProfile }}" title="{{ userAuthenticated.name }}" class="photoUser" data-err-src="images/png/avatar.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar a função FormData.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", $scope.file);

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: $rootScope.serviceBase + "users", user,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  data: {
    file: formData
  }
}).
then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  return result.data;
});
```

O suporte a essa função, é apenas em browsers novos. [Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata).

Mais informações sobre a função [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData).

O ideal seria você salvar a imagem em base 64, assim ocupa menos espaço em banco, porém há outras formas de salvar a imagem, podendo enviá-las para um Web Service, tratá-las e depois salvá-las em um servidor de arquivos, entre outras coisas. Veja se isso resolve pra você, se não, dê uma olhada em plugins do próprio Angular para fazer o upload, como por exemplo [Ng-File-Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) ou [FlowJS](https://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/).